# How to create template in the helm chart?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-secrets

I need to create template for secret value.

This is the secret file:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: secret
type: Opaque
stringData:
  "user":  "user"
  "password":  "password"
```

And this is what I have created in the _helpers.tpl

```
{{/*
  User
*/}}
{{- define "@@chartName@@.user" -}}
{{- $secret := lookup "v1" "Secret" .Release.Namespace "secret" -}}
  {{- if $secret -}}
     {{- print $secret.stringData.user}}
  {{- else -}}
     {{- fail "The secret is absent" -}}
  {{- end -}}
{{- end -}}
```

But it doesn't work and I get the error :  <$secret.stringData.user>: nil pointer evaluating interface {}.user

I have created the secret before installation helm chart and I don't know what is the reason of this error.  Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will get that error if `$secret` exists, but doesn't contain `stringData`.

At a Helm level, you can work around this by using the `default` function to force it to exist ("doesn't have `stringData`" and "doesn't have `user`" are approximately the same error):

```
{{- $secret := lookup "v1" "Secret" .Release.Namespace "secret" | default dict -}}
{{- $stringData := $secret.stringData | default dict -}}
{{- $stringData.user | required "The secret is absent" -}}
```

At a higher-level, if it's possible to read back the Secret, it probably only has the base64-encoded `data` field (even if it was created with `stringData`).  Helm provides a [`b64dec` function](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/#encoding-functions) that could decode it.  It'd be better to [refer to the secret as an environment variable](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#using-secrets-as-environment-variables) in your pod spec, or pass the value directly into Helm.

```yaml
# in a Pod spec; without using Helm `lookup`
env:
  - name: USER
    valueFrom:
      secretKeyRef:
        name: secret
        key: user
```

```
# or passed directly via Helm
{{- $credentials := .Values.credentials | default dict -}}
{{- $credentials.user | required "missing user.credentials" -}}
```